# How to get the bounds of the Google Map element with Polymer

Tags: google-maps, polymer

I have a Polymer Paper Map that I want to just show the pins of a JSON data set from Firebase. But I cannot get the Google Map bounds. Any ideas?

Comment: What does your code look like so far?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the getBounds() function? Did you check out the available features from the [**doc**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference)

Answer (score 0):

This is late, but hopefully will help future visitors.

```
document.querySelector('google-map').map.getBounds();
```